# how to extract and display the matching column after having done a match in r?

Tags: r, loops, match

I want to print the corresponding column that has been matched to the row name.

```html
List_Sample

S.No Name
2 Ba
1 Ar
5 Ca
3 Bl
4 Bu

Volume

Ar Ba Bl Bu Ca 
-5.1275 1.3465 -1.544 -0.0877 3.2955 
-2.2385 1.5065 0.193 1.082 3.074 
-5.3705 1.1285 1.966 1.183 -1.9305 
-6.4925 1.5735 1.36 -0.0761 2.0875 
-5.068 0.9455 0.947 -0.7775 3.832
```

```
Total <- as.data.frame(matrix(0, ncol = 1, nrow = 5))
for (i in 1:5)
{
  match(List_Sample$Name[i], names(Volume))
  print(List_Sample$S.No[i]*100)
  print(names(Volume[i]))
  Total = Total + Volume[i]
  print(Total)
}
View(Total)
```

When I use this code print(names(Volume[i])), it prints the name of the first column(all columns in ascending order) since here i is just a number from 1 to 5 in increasing order. What I want is to print the matching column which has been found or rather extract the matching column from the other dataframe and do some calculation.

But the output I get is just the columns of Volume in ascending order cause of the i is just 1 to 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'll find you'll get more help from folks if you post code that is easy to just copy and paste into R.  For example,

```
List_Sample <- data.frame(S.No = c(2, 1, 5, 3, 4), 
  Name = c("Ba", "Ar", "Ca", "Bl", "Bu"))

Volume <- data.frame(Ar = c(-5.1275, -2.2385, -5.3705, -6.4925, -5.068), 
  Ba = c(1.3465, 1.5065, 1.1285, 1.5735, 0.9455), 
  Bl = c(-1.544, 0.193, 1.966, 1.36, 0.947), 
  Bu = c(-0.0877, 1.082, 1.183, -0.0761, -0.7775), 
  Ca = c(3.2955, 3.074, -1.9305, 2.0875, 3.832))
```

I think you can get the code to do what you want if you save the information returned by the call to the `match()` function, I called it `j`, and then use that as your index for the rest of the `for()` loop.

```
Total <- 0
for (i in 1:5) {
  j <- match(List_Sample$Name[i], names(Volume))
  print(List_Sample$S.No[j]*100)
  print(names(Volume[j]))
  Total = Total + Volume[j]
  print(Total)
}
```

Comment: Jean V.Adams - Thank you that code works great. I will keep in mind to make the code user friendly.